# Windows 2016 cluster validation test fails - Why isn't my server listening on UDP Port 3343

Tags: windows, failovercluster

Getting a failure message similar to this

```
Network interfaces s-test-01.assemblyni.gov.uk - LOM1Port1_Mgmt and s-test-02.assemblyni.gov.uk - LOM1Port 1_Mgmt are on the same cluster network, yet address 10.63.35.30 is not reachable from 10.63.35.31 using UDP on port 3343.
```

A "netstat -a -p udp" shows that both servers are not listening on Port 3343

Since the servers themselves are not listening on this UDP port, then it can't be a firewall or network problem, correct?

Thanks for help

Comment: **Since the servers themselves are not listening on this UDP port, then it can't be a firewall or network problem, correct?** - Correct. You'll need to figure out why they're not listening on that port. Start by interrogating the event logs.